# XDocument, it says that a node is text but it is an element

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am reading an XML that contains a tag like this:

```
<source><bpt id="1">&lt;donottranslate&gt;</bpt><ph id="2">($ T_353_1 Parent ID $)</ph><ept id="1">&lt;/donottranslate&gt;</ept></source>
```

When reading `source` node I get that this node type is Text, but it should be Element.
This is an XML that I am receiving and I cannot change it.

Do you know how can I get this sorted out?

This is my code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);            

        foreach (var elUnit in doc.Descendants("trans-unit"))
        {
            if (elUnit.AttributeString("translate").ToString() == "no")
            {
                foreach (var elSource in elUnit.Elements("source"))
                {
                    string text = "";
                    foreach (var node in elSource.DescendantNodes().Where(n => XmlNodeType.Text == n.NodeType).ToList())
                    {
                        //When reading that "source" node, it enters inside this code
```

Thanks

Comment: Your xml isn't well formed- `dnt` and `bpt` intersect eachother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this checking if the node is correct or not:

```
if (System.Security.SecurityElement.IsValidText(text.XmlDecodeEntities()))
```

Answer (score 0):

First check whether your XML is wellformed

- http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp
- http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

I could get this to work

```
//using System.Xml.Linq;
var str = "<source><bpt id=\"1\">&lt;donottranslate&gt;</bpt>" +
          "<ph id=\"2\">($ T_353_1 Parent ID $)</ph>" +
          "<ept id=\"1\">&lt;/donottranslate&gt;</ept></source>";
XElement element = XElement.Parse(str);
Console.WriteLine(element);
```

The output is this

```
<source>
  <bpt id="1">&lt;donottranslate&gt;</bpt>
  <ph id="2">($ T_353_1 Parent ID $)</ph>
  <ept id="1">&lt;/donottranslate&gt;</ept>
</source>
```

Please provide some code sample for more help if this example if not suffient.